# DataTable not showing minutes and seconds

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
string command = "select  x,y,z,t,ModifiedDate " +
    " from  ZZ where PP='" + XX + "' and Type='" + YY + "' order by ModifiedDate";

connection();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(command, con);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

ModifiedDate is a DateTime - in SQL i see `"2019-07-23 12:02:35.283"`

But when i want to see "dt" in C# i only see `"2019-07-23"`

how can i see full time with minutes and seconds?

The type of the column in the `DataTable` is `DateTime`. `ZZ` is a table.

Comment: Datatable visualizer. it returns  "2019-07-23"

Comment: var ModifiedDate = item["ModifiedDate"].ToString(); =  "2019-07-23"

Comment: var x = dt.Columns["ModifiedDate"].DataType ---  x= {Name = "DateTime" FullName = "System.DateTime"}

Comment: ZZ is sql table. Not view.

Comment: Add formatting to the ToString()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

edit: added link

Comment: I see "2019-07-23", how am I going to format it.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the row to something like this:

`((DateTime)row[0]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Like how you said in the comments just add the formatting to your ToString() when assigning to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

What you had shouldn't even compile, since you can't declare both a `string` and an `SqlCommand` object with the same name in the same scope. Run the query like this:

```
string sql = @"
    select  x,y,z,t,ModifiedDate 
    from  ZZ 
    where PP= @XX and Type= @YY 
    order by ModifiedDate";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// .Net connection pooling means you really do want a new connection object most of the time. Don't try to re-use it!
// The "using" blocks make sure your objects are closed and disposed, even if an exception is thrown
using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    //use the actual column types and lengths from your database here
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@XX", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = XX;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@YY", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = YY;
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```

But this still won't fix everything. It's mainly about closing the **huge gaping-wide security hole** and potential denial-of-service issue in the original code.

The actual issue from the question is in a different place than this code. *The time portion of your `ModifiedDate`  column **is** in the resulting DataTable.* Really. I promise. If you don't see it, it's because of a DataView, format string, or other issue at the point where you try to observe or display these results.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Date` class in C# - even `DateTime.Date()` returns another `DateTime` object with an all zeros time component.

Your problem sounds very much like a Regional Settings issue, or more specifically, [`CultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8) in C#. Your default (or "current" as applied by `Thread.CurrentThread`'s [`CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.8#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_CurrentCulture) or [`CurrentUICulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture?view=netframework-4.8)) has its [`CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat?view=netframework-4.8) setup to supply date-without-time formatting.

Probably the `FullDateTimePattern` is set to `"yyyy-mm-dd"` or something equivalent.